# JavaScript cannot identify element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, safari

My JavaScript code is supposed to receive data using AJAX and display it in a DIV called "txtHint". However, this is the error I get when the code executes (I am using the build-in debugger in Safari):

> TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById("txtHint")' [null] is not an object.

Here is the code:

```
function showItem(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getitem.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now i get: 
TypeError: Result of expression 'el' [undefined] is not an object.

Does this mean my element does not exist?

Comment: Please post your markup.

Comment: Are you running this after the DOM is finished loading? If not you're trying to fetch "txtHint" before it is accessible and thus getElementById("txtHint") will return null. This might work for the callback in the ajax request since it's asynchronous, but if str == "", it's happening immediately

Comment: How do I see if the DOM is unfinished and my div hasn't been 'registered' yet?

Answer (score 2):

First, check if the element exists.

```
var el = document.getElementById('txtHint');
if ( el ) {  
   el.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Make sure you are binding this after the element has been generated in the DOM. You can also wait for the entire window to load via `window.onload = showItem`.

People use frameworks like jQuery to save time. Your code would result in something as succinct as:

```
$(function() {
   function blah(str) {
      if ( str == '' ) {
        $('#txtHint').html('')
        return;
      }

      $.ajax({ url:'blah.php', success:function(html) {
        $('#txtHint').html(html);
      } })
   }
});
```